# How does one order by a "has one" child property in Rails and ActiveRecord?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to sort by the state of an Organization's main address.

I have an Address model that has the property State

and an Organization that has_one :main_address, as: :addressable, class_name: 'Address'

So I'm trying to do something like this (not working) Organization.all.order_by(:main_address.state)

I can't figure out the syntax

Comment: Try this: `Organization.joins(:main_address).order('addresses.state')`

Comment: Perfect...put it in an answer and I'll select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Organization.joins(:main_address).order('addresses.state')` should do what you want.